# wordpress multisite subsite rewrite rules not working for videos

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, media

We have an issue on our site whereby videos uploaded to posts on subsites are returning a 404 when attempted to be viewed, whereas for instance images attached to subsite posts display just fine. We're on a pre-3.5 multsite install so blogs.dir is still in effect for us.

Videos uploaded to the primary site play just fine. When I substitute "wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/..." for "[subsite-slug]/files/..." in the URL the video plays just fine. Nothing looks amiss in .htaccess. Any ideas? Thanks!